# Is it bad behaviour to put views inside models? (Backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, backbone-relational

Hi i have a model that has models inside and inside... I need to give view to all of them and reach them in a hirearchy.

```
A Model
|
+---B Model
|   |
|   +----C Model
|   |
|   +----C Model
|
+---D Model
```

Think that all that models has views and for example when B models render function called i need to call both C models render functions.

So i decided that to create all related views inside models via overriding initialize methods.

So my question is that kind of behaviour is bad for mvc architecture? or it's natural?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think models should know about views.  It ought to be the other way 'round.

The view ought to be able to walk the model hierarchy, not the other way.

Comment: But at the other hand, my number of models are not static. It's changing always. So i think i need to create related view when model is being created. May be i can use signals for them?

Comment: You create a collection that holds all C models. Than you create a view of collection which might be an `<ul>`. Each C model has it's own view which might be a `<li>`. When model is added or removed from collection you re-render it's view, which renders `<ul>` adding a `<li>` for every C model in collection (i.e. creating new C model view and passing C model as param). You sync all that by using `events` which are property of views.